# how do I combine rows with duplicate name and retain information on the other column I want

Tags: r

How could combine rows and keep the information on the other column  I want?

for example:
I want to combine duplicate name while keeping the information that has 'g' in column 'a', if the other column e.g. column ' b'has 'NA' element from the duplicate will replace the NA.

| name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xy | w | h | i |
| xy | g | NA | k |
| x | m | l | o |
| x | g | q | r |
| z | n | o | p |

the result I'm looking for is

| name | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xy | g | h | k |
| x | g | q | r |
| z | n | o | p |

Comment: What happens if there are multiple rows without any `g` in column `a`?

Comment: @MartinGal reduce to the 'g' in column a

Comment: What if there is no `g`?

Comment: keep the rows unless there is NA in column 'a'

Comment: Please take a look at the proposed answers. Perhaps those help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to DPH's solution, but I use filtering to extract the rows containing `g`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  fill(where(~ any(is.na(.))), .direction="down") %>% 
  filter((any(a=="g") & a == "g") | !any(a=="g")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  name  a     b     c    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 xy    g     h     k    
2 x     g     q     r    
3 z     n     o     p
```

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution to your task is this (correct me if I got something wrong):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(name = c("xy", "xy", "x", "x", "z"),
                 a = c("w", "g", "m", "g", "m") ,
                 b = c("h", NA, "l", "q", "o"),
                 c = c("i", "k", "o", "r", "p"))

df %>%
  # build grouping
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>%
  # fill the groups downwards
  tidyr::fill(where(is.character), .direction = "down") %>%
  # get the last row of each group
  dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), ~last(.x))) %>%
  # ungroup as this prevents unwanted behaviour down stream
  dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  name  a     b     c
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 x     g     q     r
2 xy    g     h     k
3 z     m     o     p
```

Comment: @MartinGal you are right, thx for the correction, I just altered the code.